# File not found error because of the path?

Tags: python

I have downloaded shapenet dataset and started running the code on cluster. The error I came across is when I run generate.py file. It says the no such file or directory. The directory I have it in is `work/ws-tmp/data sets/shapenet/data/02958343/*/voxelized_point_cloud_256res_10000points.npz`. My doubt here is the path is matching but if it is relative path only. But I don’t know how the error is appearing in case if it is relative path. It might be an absolute path which can cause this error. How can I give relative path in this case scenario.

config file: Here we give configurations and path.

```
exp_name = shapenet_cars
data_dir = /work/ws-tmp/g051382-PCL_task/ndf/datasets/shapenet/data/02958343/
split_file = /work/ws-tmp/g051382-PCL_task/ndf/datasets/shapenet/data/split_cars.npz
input_data_glob = /model_obj_files/*/models/model_normalized.obj
sample_std_dev = [0.08, 0.02, 0.003]
sample_ratio = [0.01, 0.49, 0.5]
```

self.data gives me the path where the error is reflecting from (absolute path or relative path) is taken:

```
from __future__ import division
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import traceback


class VoxelizedDataset(Dataset):


    def __init__(self, mode, res, pointcloud_samples, data_path, split_file ,
                 batch_size, num_sample_points, num_workers, sample_distribution, sample_sigmas):

        self.sample_distribution = np.array(sample_distribution)
        self.sample_sigmas = np.array(sample_sigmas)

        assert np.sum(self.sample_distribution) == 1
        assert np.any(self.sample_distribution < 0) == False
        assert len(self.sample_distribution) == len(self.sample_sigmas)

        self.path = data_path
        self.split = np.load(split_file)
        # loads data from the npz file and the data in the npz file looks like
        # ['train':[file1, file2, file3, ...], 'test':[file1, file2, file3, ...], 'val':[file1, file2, file3, ...]]

        self.mode = mode
        # train or test or val

        self.data = self.split[self.mode]
        # equivalent to the above command is : data['test']
        
        print('self.mode:',self.mode)
        print('split:', self.split)
        print('data:',self.data)
        print('path:',self.path)
        self.res = res

        self.num_sample_points = num_sample_points
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.pointcloud_samples = pointcloud_samples

        self.num_samples = np.rint(self.sample_distribution * num_sample_points).astype(np.uint32)



    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        try:

            path = self.data[idx]
            print('path2:',self.path)
            input_path = path
            print('input_path:',input_path)
            samples_path = path

            voxel_path = input_path + '/voxelized_point_cloud_{}res_{}points.npz'.format(self.res, self.pointcloud_samples)
            occupancies = np.unpackbits(np.load(voxel_path)['compressed_occupancies'])
            input = np.reshape(occupancies, (self.res,)*3)

            if self.mode == 'test':
                return {'inputs': np.array(input, dtype=np.float32), 'path' : path}

            points = []
            coords = []
            df = []

            for i, num in enumerate(self.num_samples):
                boundary_samples_path = samples_path + '/boundary_{}_samples.npz'.format( self.sample_sigmas[i])
                boundary_samples_npz = np.load(boundary_samples_path)
                boundary_sample_points = boundary_samples_npz['points']
                boundary_sample_coords = boundary_samples_npz['grid_coords']
                boundary_sample_df = boundary_samples_npz['df']
                subsample_indices = np.random.randint(0, len(boundary_sample_points), num)
                points.extend(boundary_sample_points[subsample_indices])
                coords.extend(boundary_sample_coords[subsample_indices])
                df.extend(boundary_sample_df[subsample_indices])

            assert len(points) == self.num_sample_points
            assert len(df) == self.num_sample_points
            assert len(coords) == self.num_sample_points
        except:
            print('Error with {}: {}'.format(path, traceback.format_exc()))
            raise

        return {'grid_coords':np.array(coords, dtype=np.float32),'df': np.array(df, dtype=np.float32),'points':np.array(points, dtype=np.float32), 'inputs': np.array(input, dtype=np.float32), 'path' : path}

    def get_loader(self, shuffle =True):

        return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                self, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers, shuffle=shuffle,
                worker_init_fn=self.worker_init_fn)

    def worker_init_fn(self, worker_id):
        random_data = os.urandom(4)
        base_seed = int.from_bytes(random_data, byteorder="big")
        np.random.seed(base_seed + worker_id)
```

The error is shown below:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/ws-tmp/g051382-PCL_task/ndf/generate.py", line 71, in <module>
    gen_iterator(out_path, dataset, gen)
  File "/work/ws-tmp/g051382-PCL_task/ndf/generate.py", line 49, in gen_iterator
    for i, data in tqdm(enumerate(loader)):
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1005, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 819, in __next__
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
FileNotFoundError: Caught FileNotFoundError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/work/ws-tmp/g051382-PCL_task/ndf/models/data/voxelized_data_shapenet.py", line 49, in __getitem__
    occupancies = np.unpackbits(np.load(voxel_path)['compressed_occupancies'])
  File "/home/g051382/.conda/envs/NDF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 428, in load
    fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/shapenet/data/02958343/bd07cdd4397c88184ecc271292c8317/voxelized_point_cloud_256res_10000points.npz'
```

How to reslove the above mentioned error?

I tried giving the path
`../datasets/shapenet/data/02958343/*/voxelized_point_cloud_256res_10000points.npz`
but the error seems to show the path
`datasets/shapenet/data/02958343/*/voxelized_point_cloud_256res_10000points.npz`. It gives me a doubt regarding being taken absolute path. If it is not absolute path then I should not see the error because the path is existing properly. How can I get to relative path in that case.

Comment: Would you post the code where you put the path? Also, please post the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is not found it may be:

- because the path really does not exist.
- because it is not accessible from the current working directory.

Looking at your absolute path, I would suggest you check the current working directory with `os.getcwd()`. If this gives you `/work/ws-tmp` then the path configuration is okay since you can access the `datasets/...` from the current location. Otherwise you have to change the path kept by `file` so that it is relatively accessible from the current working directory.

EDIT:

Since your script executes from `/work/ws-tmp/slurm_scripts` and your data are accessible from `/work/ws-tmp/data sets`, then the relative path you should use to access your data from the current working directory is `../data sets/shapenet/data/02958343`.

Note that in your code you concatenate two parts to build up a path. This is not a good practice and I encourage you to use the `os.path` module instead! Like this: `os.path.join(input_path, "voxelized_point_cloud_{}res_{}points.npz".format( self.sample_sigmas[i]))`.

Comment: os.getcwd() gives me different location because the code is run from different location than where the datasets are present. The code is run from "work/ws-tmp/slurm_scripts" but the dataset path is different i.e; "work/ws-tmp/data sets/shapenet/data/02958343/*/voxelized_point_cloud_256res_10000points.npz". So should I change the path of datasets to slurm_scripts in this case?

Comment: @Saitarak did it work? I edited the answer with some details.